# Pygame error: Attribute Error: no attribute get_rect()

Tags: python, module, pygame, attributeerror, game-development

Trying to add a ship image to the background of the pygame terminal, so i created a Ship class and saved it in a module called ship:

```
import pygame

class Ship():

def __init__(self, screen):
    """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
    self.screen = screen
    
    # Load the ship image and get its rect.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('image/ship.bmp')
    self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    
    # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.bottom
    
def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current position."""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

then I imported the class into my main game file and tried running the code, but I keep getting an AttributeError: module 'pygame.image' has no attribute get_rect.

Here is the code on my main game file:

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
# Initialize pygame, settings and screen object.
pygame.init()
ai_settings = Settings()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
    (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

# Make a ship
ship = Ship(screen)

# Start the main loop for the game.

while True:
    
    # Watch for keyboard and mouse event.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
            
    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
```

run_game()

Please what am I doing wrong here and how can I resolve this?

Comment: `self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()` should probably be `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`.

Comment: Thanks the code runs perfectly now.

Comment: Great! I've posted it as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()
```

should be

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

e.g. You want the .rect of the image you just created with the `pygame.image.load(...` call.